# How to copy memory starting at address finer than the addressable granularity of your system?

Tags: c, memcpy

I'm thinking about [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/), where the `src` pointer that is passed might be an odd memory address.  Is this possible?  And, if so, can it be implemented?

If for my system, memory is addressable in 32bit (4Byte) blocks:

```
0x00001000
0x00001020
0x00001040
0x00001060
```

How can I copy five bytes from midway in an array whose contents begin at `0x00001000`, e.g. the contents of address `0x00001050` through `0x00001078` inclusive?

Does the `memcpy` implementation always have to copy byte-by-byte?

Comment: `memcpy` will copy starting at the address provided by the source pointer, it will copy the number of bytes you tell it to, and it will copy to the address provided in the destination pointer provided. If you provide a source pointer containing the address of the start of the 5 bytes you want, it will copy those 5 bytes. Yes, it will copy byte-by-byte.

Comment: "If for my system, memory is addressable in 32bit (4Byte) blocks:"  Not sure what you mean here.  Are you saying that all addresses must be multiples of 4 "under the hood?"  Or are you saying that a `char` has 32 bits? (Which might be two different ways of saying the same thing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine in all versions of C, all platforms - a C compiler wouldn't be compliant with the C standard if the parameters to memcpy() needed to be word-aligned.

If you look under the hood you'll see that memcpy() is always faster if src and dst are word aligned, and special tricks are needed to cope with the more general case of e.g. odd pointers, because then it needs to go down to the level of bytes. But that is not your worry - you just use the function and trust that it works.